# How to use an unlisted Python Package with 'pyproject.toml' file in Google Colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use an Unofficial Twitter API using python library called [RedGalaxy](https://github.com/Ristellise/RedGalaxy) on Google Colab. This package is not yet available on Pypi platform.

I have tried to build the package in Google colab itself but wasn't able to use it there.

```
!git clone https://github.com/Ristellise/RedGalaxy.git
!pip install -e ./RedGalaxy/.
```

Output:

```
Successfully built RedGalaxy
Successfully installed RedGalaxy-0.1.0 h11-0.14.0 httpcore-0.16.3 httpx-0.23.3 rfc3986-1.5.0
```

When I try to import library:

Code:

```
from RedGalaxy import TwitterUser
```

Output:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2f6c640e0abc> in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import asyncio
      2 
----> 3 from RedGalaxy import TwitterUser
      4 
      5 

ImportError: cannot import name 'TwitterUser' from 'RedGalaxy' (unknown location)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Would appreciate suggestions for different libraries to access Twitter API (Specially Stream functions)." - this is inappropriate for two reasons: we [don't do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) such recommendations here, and this is **not a discussion forum** - we aren't throwing around possible ways to solve your underlying problem, but instead trying to **answer a question** that will become part of a searchable Q&A library. That means questions need to stay focused, and be **one** question. I edited the question to remove this part.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git clone` and `pip install -e ./RedGalaxy/.` had caused the package to install with name:

```
-e git+https://github.com/Ristellise/RedGalaxy.git@4258602c48895e4b1b7e352479a44a3322c3722d#egg=RedGalaxy
```

as compared to name of packages installed using pip:

```
tensorflow==2.12.0
torch @ https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118/torch-2.0.0%2Bcu118-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Installing package using
`!pip install git+https://github.com/Ristellise/RedGalaxy.git@main`
will resolve package name to

```
RedGalaxy @ git+https://github.com/Ristellise/RedGalaxy.git@4258602c48895e4b1b7e352479a44a3322c3722d
```

which can be imported in code.